# JS Negative Lookbehind

Tags: javascript, regex

https://regex101.com/r/ZYsdyT/1

Pattern: `(?<!{)<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>(?!})|{[\w]*}`

1. matches: `<n>programming</n>`
2. matches: `{sometext}`
3. matches: `<n>{programming}</n>`
4. no match: `{<n>programming</n>}`

The above regex does work, the challenge I am having is that negative lookbehind isn't supported in the version of JS i am using. Is there anything I can do to make sure that example 4 above doesn't match without using a negative look behind? How can i adjust the regex? Thank you.

Comment: Should it match `abc {<1>something</1> def` or `abc <1>something</1>} def`?

Comment: Capture and filter them from your results
https://jsfiddle.net/6hapkmdo/

Comment: @Nick No. For every opening bracket or tag, there needs to be a closing one.

Answer (score 1):

You could match what you don't want, and capture what you do want. The values that you want to keep are in group 2.

Groups 1 and 3 are captures used for the backreference `\1` and `\3` to match the same opening and closing value.

```
{<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>}|(<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\3>|{\w*})
```

The pattern matches:

- `{<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>}` Match `{<n>` till `</n>}`
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\3>` Match `<n>` till `</n>`
  - `|` Or
  - `{\w*} Match` {`optional word chars and`}`
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6PFW3T/1)

```js
const regex = /{<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\1>}|(<(\d+)>[^<>]*<\/\3>|{\w*})/g;
const str = `Life <0>is </1>amazingly beautiful<1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.
Life <0>is <1>amazi</3>ngly <2>beau<3>tif</3>ul</2></1></0> and <3>progra<4>mm</4>ing</3> is <4>fun</4>.
Life <0>is <1>amazingly</1> <2>beautiful</2></0> and <3>programming</3> is <4>fun</4>.
Life <0>is <1>amazingly beautiful</1></0> and <2>programming</2> is <3>fun</3>.
Life <0>is <1>amazingly <2>{beautiful}</2></1></0> and <3>programming</3> is <4>fun</4>.
Life <0>is {<1>hihi</1>}amazingly <2>beautif{ul</2></1></0> a{asd}nd <3>p{r}ogr<4>amming</4></3> is <4>fun</4>.
Life <0>is </0><0>a<1>{maz}ingly <2>beautiful</2></1></0> and <3>progr<4>amming</4></3> is <4>fun</4>.

<1>programming</1>
matches: {sometext}
matches: <2>{programming}</2>
no match: {<3>programming</3>}`;
let m;

Array.from(str.matchAll(regex), m => {
  if (m[2] !== undefined) console.log(m[2]);
});
```

Comment: Indeed, this is best approach i.e. capture and discard

Comment: Is there no better way? My plan was to recursively remove the matches in order to validate the string. With your approach i wouldn't be able to achieve that since i don't want it to match `{<n>something</n>}`.